# Different levels of access for AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I'm trying to build a web app that can be accessed by any user that signs up with facebook. 
I want to use AWS Cognito to speed up the development for users management.

It has to have 3 type of users:

- Normal users - any user that logs in with facebook
- Editors - users that have a different access level (IAM role?), they can call a specific AWS Lambda function, that normal users can't call.
- Administrators - users that can modify the status of normal users to make them editors or admins

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've set up AWS Cognito Identity Pool but I'm not sure if I have to set up a User Pool or how do I assign a different role or policy to a user to make him an admin or editor (different access levels for other AWS resources), if I can get in my web app the users list from Cognito (only for an authenticated admin) and how do I allow him to modify other users roles.

Some tutorial, documentation or at least a short description of how can I do this would help me a lot.

Optional: let users to not only sign up with facebook but also with email/pass, and have the same functionality.

Comment: Hi @Cristian, I have a similar requirement like this. Please share your solution for this one. I'm planning to use Cognito as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use 'Role Based Access Control' feature of Cognito federated identities. This is the relevant part of the doc:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html

If you are only using Facebook, you can use Facebook sub to assign appropriate role.

If you are using username and password based sign-in with user pool, you can use group support and create editors group and assign appropriate permissions.

Instead of managing Administrators with federated identities or user pool, probably directly using IAM user will be a better idea. This IAM user will have full permission to modify/add identity pool rules or user pool groups.

Comment: So then the Administrators will be IAM users and the editors and normal users will be Cognito users? And every Admin will have the permission to change the editors policy to add cognito user ids one by one in it? So that cognito users added to the editor policy will have editor rights.

Comment: To clarify, by 'change the editors policy'  if you meant the Cognito rule based policy, then yes.

Comment: ok, so the last questions: 1) is it a good practice to have the list of ids (editors in this case) in the policy and keep adding the new ones in there?  2) can I restrict the admin so that he can only allow the users to be editors and access that lambda function (so they won't be able to give super users access to normal users)  3) will it work the same for facebook logged users and cognito users logged with username/password ?

Comment: 1) I don't see any other way if you are using Facebook. If you are using Cognito user pools for username/password based access, it is much easier since you need to just add user to 'Editor' group. 2) Yes, you can limit the admin IAM user privilege with IAM, and he will only be able to assign a role with a permission to another user which are subset of his permission 3) Yes, you can use rule based mechanism for both, but Cognito groups will be more handy for user with username/password.