# Different access tokens for users using aws Cognito for authorisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to provide differential access to services behind an aws api-gateway, lets say simplistically split into 2 user groups user-a and user-b that each can access /routeA or /routeB but not the other.

User Authentication is via Cognito User Pool with 2 user groups defined. Front End is React and Amplify.

I am going round in circles with this having tried a few approaches. Running this decision tree [select-auth-method](https://theburningmonk.com/2020/06/how-to-choose-the-right-api-gateway-auth-method/) points to using Cognito AuthZ which is fine in itself as I am using Cognito for AuthN.

So far none of the examples/tutorials/articles/videos have demonstrated how to block some users while enabling others. I have tried:

Cognito User Pool Authorizer - identity token based but seems to just AuthZ any logged in user. I could possibly attach IAM Roles to the user groups ?

Custom Lambda Authorizer - Works well on checking for the valid user-group in the Access Token and dynamically creating the required permissions but, some additional latency from a λ and no check that the access token is current. Starts to feel like I am writing code for a system that exists somewhere else?

Cognito OAuth - Spent some time trying to understand this. So I create a Resource Server attached to the Cognito app client and create some custom scopes that I can then reference in the Api-g Authorizers. Fine, but how to I create two different access tokens for the users that have different scopes? So far my understanding seems to suggest that it is another binary AuthZ approach, but articles suggest (but don't demonstrate!) it is capable of granular permissions? I must be missing something.

I also saw this [2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555924/different-levels-of-access-for-aws-cognito) but things may have moved on with better approaches?

I am minded to go OAuth route as it seems more of an industry standard approach and promises much but need a bit of insight as to how to enable different access tokens for different users.

Comment: Found an article which states " One disadvantage with Cognito is that there is no way to restrict the scopes on a per user basis. For ex: in some identity providers like ForgeRock, Okta, AuthO etc, you can restrict the scopes on a per user basis based on a user's attribute/group membership" ie. what I want to do.  It goes on: "One option...start the Auth flow with minimum scope eg read access and get other scopes from Cognito when the user tries to execute the operation".  How ?

Answer (score 3):

So the answer is that Cognito does not implement the OAuth2 functionality that I need but others do. Given the following excerpt from AuthO docs, this feels like a better solution path...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be very useful if we could just restrict endpoints on the cognito:groups that are in the tokens,but this functionality isn't there.

There are a few options that might suit you, one is just put the users in different user pools and create different authorizers for those pools and assign them the routes.

Another is OAuth scopes, you can create two app clients each with different scopes then configure the scopes in APIGW. Note that in this case you need to pass the access token to APIGW not the ID token.

In either case if you are using Hosted UI you will have a problem as you will now have two Hosted UIs and it may not be straightforward knowing which one to display to a user until they have entered their email address.

BTW if you are not using Hosted UI you will be unable to use OAuth scopes.

You can also assign IAM roles to the cognito:groups and allow these access to the APIGW resources you want. This is probably the easiest method although it is not as simple as you would probably like.

The final way I can think of is writing a custom authorizer, I would avoid this if you can, I have done it a few times now and it has never been enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems to be to authorise users depending on their permissions, as opposed to needing different types of access token.

I would recommend sending the Cognito access token to the API and receiving it like this in the API:

- Level 1: Validate the access token first to check it is not expired etc
- Level 2: Consider checking a scope to ensure that the token is for your API
- Level 3: Check finer grained claims such as group membership or anything else that makes sense for your scenario. Your API can get groups by sending the access token to the Cognito user info endpoint.

**DESIGN PATTERN**

This [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) of mine describes the pattern and use of claims caching.

Here is some lambda authorizer sample code, though the same behaviour can be implemented in your API directly and my blog has some examples of this:

- [Cognito Claims Based Authorization](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing-oauth/src/oauth/oauthAuthenticator.ts)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I moved on to Auth0 and refactored my api gateway from REST to HTTP which has native JWT Authorizers as well as other significant benefits. So the steps you describe are handled by Auth0's authZ flow. No need for Custom Authorizers. Cognito's implementation of authZ leaves a lot to be desired in comparison but it was the integration of an HTTP api with Auth0's authN and authZ that really differentiated the two approaches largely from the JWT authZ and the ability to easily set scopes on route by route basis. I am fortunate in being able to move from REST to HTTP api so easily

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-aws-http-apis-with-jwt-authorizers/

Comment: Good to hear you've resolved your problem - I think it is always good to start with an awareness of standard behaviour - vendor solutions are often pretty limited, as you've pointed out.